# How to update a global variable in jinja template?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I am dynamically replacing my div content with the new content. My new content is the record fetched from the database which is stored as a list of a list in variable data. Every time when the submit button is clicked, the  content should be replaced by the next item from the list. I have declared a global variable I to fetch the corresponding item from data[] and I am trying to increment my i. But every time i is initialized to the original value. Please help. I have attached my code here.

```
<html>  
<head>
  {% set i=0%}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ReplaceContentInContainer(id, content) {
      var container = document.getElementById(id);
      container.innerHTML = "";
      container.innerHTML = document.getElementById('blockOfStuff').innerHTML;
    }
  </script>
  <script id="blockOfStuff" type="text/html">
    <div id="d1">
      {% set i=i+1%} {% for item in data[i]%}
      <tr>
        {{item}}
      </tr>
      <br> {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('d1','')">
    </div>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="d1">
    {% for item in data %}
    <tr>
      {% for val in item %}
      <td>{{val}}</td>
      <br> {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('d1','')"> {% break %} {% endfor %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code to send `blockOfStuff` to server to render it?

Comment: My blockofStuff is just an html to add new item from my data[].So basically when my i is 1 my item will be data[1] and it will replace data[0].Then next time when submit buttton is clicked,data[1] will disappear (when control goes to function ReplaceContentInContainer(id, content) ) and will be replaced by data[2] and this process will continue till i==len(data).

Comment: your template rendering with jinja2 is happening on client side?

Comment: Yes,it is happening on client side.I am returning the above code (survey.html)  from my app.py file.It seems the scope of variable ends after loop is finished in jinja because my 'i' is getting incremented when it enters the for loop for the first time.After that when loop is finished,i is again initialized to original value even when it is declared globally.

Comment: Is it possible to create a fiddle of it?